# R: Make character string refer to an object

Tags: r, object, character

I have a large list of files (`file1`, `file2`, `file3`, etc.) and, for each analysis, I want to refer to two files from this list (e.g. `function(file1,file2)`). When I try to do this using `paste0("file", pairs[1,x]` I get back the character string `"file1"` rather than the object `file1`.

How can I refer to the objects rather than create a character string?

Thank you very much!

Additional comment:

- pairs is a 2xn matrix where each column is the combination of files for one analysis (e.g. pairs[1,1] = 1 and pairs[2,1] = 2 for the comparison between file1 and file2).

Comment: Are the files actually in a proper R list object? If not, they probably should be. Having variable names with important information in them isn't a good strategy. You can use `get()` to get the value of a variable via a string, but that's generally a sign of a poor design choice in R.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do with those files. Maybe see `?connections`

Comment: If what you write is true and you have a `list` of files `file1, file2, file3, ...`, and the `list` is named (if not, see e.g. `?setNames`, then you can do for instance `my_list_of_files[["file1"]]` to retrieve `file1`.

Answer (score 10):

Are you looking for `get()`???

```
a <- 1:5
> get("a")
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 3):

How to get the variable from a string containing the variable name:

```
> a = 10
> string = "a"
> string
[1] "a"
> eval(parse(text = string))
[1] 10
> eval(parse(text = "a"))
[1] 10
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative:

```r
eval(as.name("file"))
```